# Google Analytics Search Term Exclusions doesn't work?

Tags: google-analytics, keywords, search

I have a question concerning GA Search Term Exclusions. I excluded our brand search terms, but they still show up under "Acquisition" > "Channel" > "Organic Search". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Changes in GA settings (e.g. search term exclusion) does not affect a historical data. Searches for brand terms does not appear since the exclusion (try to change viewed time period)